# In cocoa, how do I save text with a particular UTI

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, uti

I would like to export some data as a certain UTI type (e.g. public.text).  If I save the text file, I can see with mdls that the UTI type is public.data - but I can't find anywhere find any API's to choose with UTI the file is.

It seems to work if I add an extension '.txt' but I don't want that.  In fact, I need to set the file to have certain UTI so another program can load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can export something with a `public.text` UTI. An UTI sort of represents a kind of file abstractly. That is, with this particular UTI you can reference all kind of text files, regardless of their extension (.txt, .text, .md, .html etc.). I think that the .txt extension is the best one to represent a general text file.

If the other program you mention is able to open files with the `public.text` UTI, then it will also accept .txt (and all those other extensions).

You can read Apple's [Introduction to Uniform Type Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html) for more info about UTIs.

Comment: Correct. A UTI is not file metadata — that is, it's not stored with the file. It is *derived from* file metadata. (It is, perhaps, file meta-metadata.)